# Objects nests when bringing the object to another file

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and am experimenting with something but came to this problem where when I call a object in another file where I inherit these values etc it just makes like a new object en put the original object into that new one. It is probably explained like a mess but Ill make it clear with some examples. Can someone just explain to me how this works?

**This is the base file. The tirth route is the one where it happens, you see that i want to give the items to that file.**
***The result when you log the items here is items { ... } (What I want)***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Home from "./components/Home.jsx";
import AboutUs from "./components/AboutUs.jsx";
import Contact from "./components/Contact.jsx";
import Overview from "./components/Overview.jsx";
import Nav from "./components/Nav.jsx";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { items: { 1551204339467: "Hi", 1551204339469: 
    "123Test" } };
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <Nav />

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={AboutUs} />
          <Route path="/overview" render={() => <Overview items={items} 
          />} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        </Switch>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

***This is the file where it gives me a nested object like items: { items: { ... }}***

```
import React from "react";
import ItemsList from "./ItemsList.jsx";

const Overview = items => {
  console.log(items);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Overview</h1>
      <ItemsList items={items} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Overview;
```

**Can someone explain me what is the reason for this is automatically nesting? TNX!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your third route-

```
<Route path="/overview" render={() => <Overview items={items} 
      />} />
```

You are making use of the *render* method instead of the *component* method which are available out of the three methods to render something with the `<Route>`

with *render*, you can pass a function that will be called when the location matches.

so what does your function does here?
It is returning a `component` in which you are passing *items* props having the value of `{items}`

```
const { items } = this.state;
```

Here you are making use of ES6 destructuring. Basically, getting *items* from the state object which in itself is another object.

Your `Overview` component will be receiving `Items` prop having value of `Items` object, along with the other route props like match, history, location.

[Source](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func)